# Problems to automate ‘Share’ in Android using Appium

Tags: kotlin, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation, appium-android

sorry for my question, maybe it'll be very simple the answer but I'm trying to automate an app using Appium and the assertion for one of the test cases is to verify if the bottom sheet to share documents, images, etc is visible or not to the user. But I'm not able to handle the elements inside of this bottom sheet.

For example:

[image: Package of the element + id to call share function] 
***Package of the element/id of the button that open bottom sheet***

[image: Package of the element + id when the bottom sheet is opened]
***Package of the element/id when the bottom sheet is opened***

[image]
***Example of Bottom Sheet***

I already tried to get the context, package to see if both are different (I mean, before and after I click on the button who calls the bottom sheet) and even thought handle with the elements of this bottom sheet directly, without any treatment, but no success.

Example:

```
    fun getCurrentPackage(): String {
        return (driver as AndroidDriver<MobileElement>).currentPackage
    }
    //returns the package of the app

    fun getCurrentActivity(): String {
        return (driver as AndroidDriver<MobileElement>).currentActivity()
    }
    //returns the activity before the bottom sheet
```

Moreover, I tried to use the method 'getContextHandles' using a similar snippet as shown below but both contexts are natives so didn't work as well.

```
//switch to Native view from webView
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
 for (String contextName : contextNames) {
 if (contextName.contains("NATIVE"))
 driver.context(contextName);
 }
```

Comment: Declare a WebELement using the root id or class of the  bottom sheet and assert that element exists. Or using your existing action_share id.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to sleep until bottom sheet is opened and try to find "Share" Text and click on them.

if disabled click on "Share" Text , you can get x and y location of "Share" text and try to click coordinate x , y - 20.

i hope, help you

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for all answers but I resolved in this way:

@AndroidFindBy(id = "android:id/title")

Putting the entire path of the locator, the Appium is able to handle in this way.